# Find a pattern into a string without space

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I'm looking for a way to find and extract the string matching a pattern in a string without a space :

```
string regexpattern = @"[A-Z]{4}\d{4}$";                    // ex : BERF4787            
string stringWithoutSpace = "stringsampleBERF4787withpattern";

string stringMatchPattern = ???         //I want to get BEFR4787 in this variable
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. The problem in your pattern is the `$` which matches the end of a string. Since in your example the `"BERF4787"` is located in the middle of the string you should simply remove it:

```
string regexpattern = @"[A-Z]{4}\d{4}";                    // ex : BERF4787            
string stringWithoutSpace = "stringsampleBERF4787withpattern";
```

If you want to match your pattern in a string you can use the [Regex.Match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz(v=vs.110).aspx) method which returns an object of type [Match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match(v=vs.110).aspx).
To get the matched value you need to use the [Match.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.value(v=vs.110).aspx) property like this:

```
string stringMatchPattern = Regex.Match(stringWithoutSpace, regexpattern).Value;
```